# How to redirect Error Page and perform Routes in Zend Framework 1.x

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-route

How to perform routes in Zend Framework 1.x and also redirect custom error messages?

Comment: @hakre I just wanted to write all in one for anyone learning ZF1... have been helping people with same stuff all the time so thought of creating it after reading : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: KarmicDice: That is perfectly valid, please don't feel offended by my rather quick comment. You probably might want to outline with your question a little bit more what the original issue was. I can see both questions belong to each other. I also did not notice that you answered your own question. So I thought it might would have been helpful for you in case you're not confident with given answer(s). But obviously, this is a bit out of date now :) I stand corrected. And yes, I do that, too, answering own questions. I think it's a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform customized routes:

Put the following in your `bootstrap.php` file

```
function _initRoutes() {
    $front_controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front_controller->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute('customName', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/customName/:dataVariable', array('controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourAction')
    ));
}
```

then, in your controller action, you will access it with a data variable which you have just set.

For example:
For Category - Post display

```
function _initRoutes() {
    $front_controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front_controller->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute('category', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/post/:postId', array('controller' => 'category', 'action' => 'post')
    ));
}
```

then in category controller and post action, I will use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('postId');`

which will frame url as : example.com/post/123

ZF1 comes you a predefined ErrorController, you can use it.

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

  public function errorAction() {
    $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

    if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject) {
      $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
      return;
    }

    switch ($errors->type) {
      case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
      case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
      case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
        // 404 error -- controller or action not found
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
        $priority = Zend_Log::NOTICE;
        $this->view->error_code = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
        $this->view->message = "Page Not Found";
        $this->renderScript('error/error_404.phtml');
        break;
      default:
        // application error
        print_r($this->getResponse());
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
        $priority = Zend_Log::CRIT;
        $this->view->error_code = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
        $this->view->message = 'Application error';
        if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
        $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
        $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
        $this->renderScript('error/error_500.phtml');
        }

    // conditionally display exceptions
        if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
                $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        }

        $this->view->request = $errors->request;
        $this->view->error_code = $this->getResponse()->getHttpResponseCode();
        $this->renderScript('error/error_500.phtml');
        break;
    }

    // Log exception, if logger available
    if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
      $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
      $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
    }

    // conditionally display exceptions
    if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
      $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
    }

    $this->view->request = $errors->request;
  }

  public function getLog() {
    $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')) {
      return false;
    }
    $log = $bootstrap->getResource('Log');
    return $log;
  }

}
```

You can set [HTTP_STATUS_CODES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) from the list but, make sure you give user's browser and search bots the right statuses.